# how to add custom action buttons in jquery datatable edit/delete

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I tried adding the action buttons in my ajax datatable edit/delete but its not working. I tried adding it using data option but its messing up the ajax call
here is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                
    $(document).ready(function(){

       $(document).on("click" , "#add-stockin" , function(){

        window.location.href = './stockin.php';

     }); 
 
    var table = $('#table1').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
      ajax: {
        url : "http://localhost/cokeinventory/rest-api/api-search-stockin.php",
        dataSrc: "doc",
        
       
      },
      columns: [
        { data: 'stock_id'},
        { data: 'item_name'},
        { data: 'unit' },
        { data: 'stockin_qty' },
        { data: 'barcode_number' },
        { data: 'barcode_label' },
        { data: 'balquantity' },
        {data: "stock_id" , render : function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
              return type === 'display'  ?
                '<a href="" id='deletebtn';?>'+ data +'" >Delete<i class="fe fe-delete"></i></a>' :
                
            }},

      ],
    });

  });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code to add custom action links to jQuery datatable:

Here please refer official documentation for the same: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/inTableControls.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click" , "#add-stockin" , function(){
            window.location.href = './stockin.php';
        });

        var table = $('#table1').DataTable( {
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            ajax: {
                url : "http://localhost/cokeinventory/rest-api/api-search-stockin.php",
                dataSrc: "doc",
            },
            columns: [
                { data: 'stock_id'},
                { data: 'item_name'},
                { data: 'unit' },
                { data: 'stockin_qty' },
                { data: 'barcode_number' },
                { data: 'barcode_label' },
                { data: 'balquantity' },
                {
                    data: null,
                    className: "dt-center editor-delete",
                    orderable: false,
                    "mRender" : function ( data, type, row ) {
                        return '<a href="" id="deletebtn_' + data.stock_id+'" >Delete <i class="fe fe-delete"></i></a>';
                    }
                }

            ],
        });

    });
```

Comment: this is not working. its even messing up with the api call
does it works on ur end?

Comment: how we can pass the id ? here like id="deletebtn_' + data.stock_id +'" >Delete 
can we pass it like this? cuz data itself isnt something have to define what we are passing from this data variable

Comment: I have added "mRender" function into the action column code. Please check with the updated code. You will get the row data in it in which you can get the stock_id of the specific row.  If still does not work, I will provide the sample source code.

Comment: return '<button id="deletebtn"  value=' + data.stock_id+' >Delete <i class="fe fe-delete"></i></button>';

I updated the button and put id on it to get the value of this button but on all the rows i am getting the same id


$("body").on("click", "#deletebtn", function(){
      var val = $("#deletebtn").val();
      alert(val);
 });

can you suggest me whats happening here?

Comment: I wan the stock_id of any selected item so i could send that id to my api for deletion @Aniket Panchal